# Angular: Push, then remove an item

Tags: angular

This might be seen as a duplicated of [Angular - push object to list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14289530/angular-push-then-delete-an-item)

I am trying to push a new object to a list and then delete it.

component.ts file:

```js
  newActivity: Activity = {
    id: 0,
    description: '',
    type: { id: 0, description: '' },
  };
```

In my HTML file I am applying binding so that **newActivity** property is **populated correctly**. I then call a WebApi service to save it. Right after that I have the following code:

```js
  this.myActivityService.saveActivity(this.newActivity).subscribe(
   //CODE TO handle success or error
  );

  this.listOfActivities.push(this.newActivity);

  this.resetNewActivity();
```

where **resetNewActivity()** method is:

```js
    resetNewActivity(): void {
    this.newActivity.id = 0;
    this.newActivity.description = '';
    this.newActivity.type = { id: 0, description: '' };
  }
```

The newActivity object is added to the list using array's `push()`. However, as soon as the `resetNewActivity()` method is executed, the new Activity that was added to the list is reset as well.

How, can I isolated the reset method from the item that was added to the list of activites?

Comment: You are dealing with the array, array index starts with 0. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
resetNewActivity(): void {
    this.newActivity = new Activity();
}
```

(or)

```
resetNewActivity(): void {
    this.newActivity = {
        id: 0,
        description: '',
        type: { id: 0, description: ''},
    };
}
```

you will have to assign a new object in resetNewActivity() as modifying the attributes of existing object will modify wherever it has been added.. to lists or display or anywhere...

This is not a concept specific to Angular, this is in general for all object oriented programming...

Comment: Thanks @JamesAshok. Both solutions worked for me. I opted to using the first one. It's more clean. Since, I am kind of new to Angular I was not sure at all how arrays worked here. Glad to hear and see it's the same concept :)

Answer (score 0):

Few things to be considered here:

- You should not assign id value manually, should be generated uniquely and dynamically. check the working solution.
- Modularity should there when you code something and focus on loosely coupled with single responsibility.
- If the above two things are taken care, your life will be easy and you can reset your object in a single line of code.

check the working solution and try to run from menu options then open console to see the results.

[working Solution in Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOEDeAoZQ5YAEwC5kQBXAWwCNoBuAokiAZwSmEzGAHsQFdmG4gA5swC+eBABs47dsgCCCPgDdgYdMnxFCpCtXpMWrDlx59Bw0aEnnCAfR3ZkFDNmYHkCQSJQVOr8UAAUAJT6vkRgABbA7AB0pMgAvMgA1CAQAO7IACJwkJE+MYTxiUlsnNy8AiDpyADkzWXllcmuWCgZ0eUGqRSZlHmFxRCRADROA8g1VvW2Lc2zBjK+GzIacFCjuWqa2roZOfmHwFo6pXgwVCDqDchQHBBgAPJ0AFaR0WcXVxO+1Uj0BNw2-1Bx2qljqNkaGQARJ1iMozvNYdYGoifP4QOx+HIIEk5PxxGFIUcdBEfC92G9Pj8abIAoTiaTyZTLscaUA)

Answer (score 0):

when you make push(this.newActivity) push the same object always, so you can use spreadOperator push({...this.newActivity,type:{...this.newActivity.type}}) to create a different object or some type of deep copy of object

A silly example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yyyh5v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
newActivity= {
    id: 0,
    description: '',
    type: { id: 0, description: ''},
  };
  listOfActivities: any[] = [];
  click(){
    this.listOfActivities.push({...this.newActivity,type:{...this.newActivity.type}})
  }
  change()
  {
    this.listOfActivities[0].type.id=10;
  }

<pre>
  {{listOfActivities|json}}
</pre>
<button (click)="click()">add</button>
<button (click)="change()">change</button>
```